# PHP cafile below version 5.6

Tags: php, ssl, composer-php

whats the equiliant parameter or method to include certificates so that you can establish ssl connections in PHP 5.5.* .

I stuck with that version and can't update it and i neet to include a certifictaion file for a composer update. 
I know that i have to use the openssl.cafile parameter in PHP 5.6 and everything is fine. But in my usecase im clueless.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> whats the equiliant parameter or method to include certificates so that you can establish ssl connections in PHP 5.5.* .

There isn't one.

This was a [new feature in PHP 5.6](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php):

> All encrypted client streams now enable peer verification by default. By default, this will use OpenSSL's default CA bundle to verify the peer certificate. In most cases, no changes will need to be made to communicate with servers with valid SSL certificates, as distributors generally configure OpenSSL to use known good CA bundles.
>
> The default CA bundle may be overridden on a global basis by setting either the openssl.cafile or openssl.capath configuration setting, or on a per request basis by using the [`cafile`](https://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php#context.ssl.cafile) or [`capath`](https://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php#context.ssl.capath) context options.

However, Composer has [its own `cafile` setting](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#cafile) that you should be able to use instead:

> `cafile`
>
> Location of Certificate Authority file on local filesystem. In PHP 5.6+ you should rather set this via openssl.cafile in php.ini, although PHP 5.6+ should be able to detect your system CA file automatically.

I recommend setting this via [Composer's command-line config interface](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#config), e.g something like

```
composer global config cafile <your-setting>
```

Comment: Not sure if maybe the syntax has changed in the intervening years, but the command is `composer config --global cafile <path-to-ca>`. Confirm with `composer config --list`